# Create folder in Windows CE

Tags: vb.net, windows-ce

I am working on an old application running on a Windows CE device. This is old software that is still in use.

As of now, they need to create the folder on the flash drive (there are no drive letters). My idea was to create the folder if missing. However, it gives an error when creating the directory.

The folder is used to save data for later use.

Any ideas on how create a folder from SW?
Here is my VB code:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        If Not Directory.Exists("QuaData") Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory("QuaData")
        End If
```

Comment: That looks more like Vb.Net code (which I don't know) rather than VB6 to me. If so, the tag is wrong.

Comment: What is the error that occurs? That's important information...

Comment: The error happens on the line Directory.CreateDirectory("QuaData")
With the directory in place there are no problems. It just crashes on the device, I dont know how to get a better error message

Comment: I don't get it - I added a try catch to show the exception, and it works now. Something must have gone wrong in the system on first attempt